# How can I load an image from URL without extension

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'd like to load an image from a URL but it doesn't work because the link doesn't have an extension 
Can this be solved??? 
URL example : http://d1s5a4e3za7rni.cloudfront.net/Custom/Content/Products/10/13/1013450_purificador-de-agua-electrolux-pc41x-prata_s4_636822411415208179

Example on device :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoiKX.jpg)

Comment: "It" doesn't work--what? Look up "content type".

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ysC4ZzG.jpg

Comment: Don't show imagem on cellphone.
Only don't show and not log.

Comment: @chrylis I update the question. Please look the example on device.
Obs: Don't show log with erros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

If your `Web server` serves an `image` at that `URL`, with a valid image `MIME type`, `Glide` will handle it. **Glide doesn't care about the extension, it loads the byte stream returned by the server**, it wants a `valid URL` that supplies a valid image `MIME type`.

**Example:**

```
// For a simple view:
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView yourImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_id);

  Glide.with(this).load("image_url").into(yourImageView);
}
```

To use Glide in your project see [download-setup](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html).

Comment: And you should add this in the Gradle (app)

      `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' `