# Glide FileNotFoundException

Tags: image, kotlin, filenotfoundexception, loadimage

سلام عليكم

I want to load image with Glide but I got this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://via.placeholder.com/600/1e5390
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:102)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:56)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:276)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
```

This is the image url:
https://via.placeholder.com/600/1e5390

And this is the Glide code:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.bindImage( imgUrl: String?) {
        imgUrl?.let {
            val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
            Glide.with(this.context)
                .load(imgUri)
                .apply(
                    RequestOptions()
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
                )
              
                .into(this)

    }
}
```

And use it here :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:imageUrl="@{photoObject.photoUrl}"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_broken_image" />
```

Thank you :))

Comment: I guess, problem is with image url.
I tried with 2 image url and working fine.
If your Web server serves an image at that URL, with a valid image MIME type, Glide will handle it.  May be your server does not serving a valid image MIME type.
You can see this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296248/how-can-i-load-an-image-from-url-without-extension for more.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solve my problem:

```
val theImage = GlideUrl(
        imgUrl, LazyHeaders.Builder()
            .addHeader("User-Agent", "5")
            .build()
    )
```

Add user agent header to Glide

Full code :

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.bindImage( imgUrl: String?) {


    val theImage = GlideUrl(
        imgUrl, LazyHeaders.Builder()
            .addHeader("User-Agent", "5")
            .build()
    )

    theImage.let {
        Glide.with(this.context)
            .load(theImage)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)

            )
            .into(object : CustomViewTarget<ImageView, Drawable>(this) {
                override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {}
                override fun onResourceCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                    this@bindImage.setImageDrawable(resource)
                }
            })    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@BindingAdapter("app:setPhoto")
fun ImageView.setPhoto(purl: String?) {
    val theImage = GlideUrl(
        purl,LazyHeaders.Builder()
            .addHeader("User-Agent", "5")
            .build()
    )
    theImage.let {
        Glide.with(this.context)
            .load(theImage)
            .into(this)
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain this code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, get agent:

```
val agent = WebView(this.context).settings.userAgentString
val glideUrl = GlideUrl(
           "url_here",
            LazyHeaders.Builder().addHeader("User-Agent", agent).build()
        )
Glide.with(context)
     .asBitmap()
     .load(glideUrl)
     .into(this)
```