# Can't load image from server

Tags: android, image, kotlin

How to show image from this Url :
https://via.placeholder.com/600/1e5390

inside Glide ?
When I'm trying to load it into Glide from server it just show the error placeHolder with no reason !

What can I do?

Comment: What have you tried? show the code

Comment: @mightWOZ
It's all here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69576936/glide-filenotfoundexception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Glide FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69576936/glide-filenotfoundexception)

Comment: No It's also me who asked this question

Answer (score -1):

Try with Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context).load("https://via.placeholder.com/600/1e5390").fit().centerCrop()
.placeholder(your placeholder)
.error(your error image)
.into(yourimageview);
```

Comment: any reason for -1 ????

Comment: i'm guessing because OP is asking for Glide and not Picasso

Comment: There is a question mark after glide. Image is 600*600 . Glide download the image as per by the image view size and Picasso download the complete image. there might be a possibility for image view size issue.

Comment: I wanna to do it with Glide 
check here for more details : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69576936/glide-filenotfoundexception